# Grouping in SELECT statement with two columns that contain different values among rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a SQL query I am performing against some tables SQL Server database. The result set looks something like this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | InvoiceNumber | InvoiceID
-------------------------------------------------------
1        1         1          1234            1
1        1         1          5678            2
```

I only want to get back the row with the smallest InvoiceID and its corresponding InvoiceNumber.

I apply `min(InvoiceID)` in the SELECT statement. In the GROUP BY clause, I am grouping by every column except InvoiceNumber and InvoiceID. I am getting an error since InvoiceNumber isn't contained in an aggregate function in the SELECT statement and isn't present in the GROUP BY clause.

How do I structure the query so I only get back the row with the smallest InvoiceID and the corresponding InvoiceNumber?

**Edit**

Here is some additional information:

The result set is actually going to contain many rows. It's only occassionally that multiple rows will have the same values for Column1, Column2, and Column3, but different values for the InvoiceNumber and InvoiceID. So a better example of the result set would look like this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | InvoiceNumber | InvoiceID
-------------------------------------------------------
1        1         1          1234            1
1        1         1          5678            2
2        1         1          1287            3
2        1         2          1287            3
2        2         1          1287            3
3        1         1          5555            4
3        1         2          5555            4
```

So when Column1, Column2, and Column3 are the same, I only want the result with the smallest InvoiceID, and whatever the InvoiceNumber was for the row with the smallest InvoiceID. Here's what I want it to actually look like in this case:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | InvoiceNumber | InvoiceID
-------------------------------------------------------
1        1         1          1234            1
2        1         1          1287            3
2        1         2          1287            3
2        2         1          1287            3
3        1         1          5555            4
3        1         2          5555            4
```

Only the second row was removed because it had a smaller InvoiceID and was the only row that had the same values for Column1, Column2, and Column3 as a different row.

Here's what my SQL query currently looks like:

```
SELECT c.CollectionID
    , p.Account
    , d.TransactionID
    , id.InvoiceNumber
    , i.InvoiceID
FROM collection c
INNER JOIN documents d on c.GlobalCollectionID = d.GlobalCollectionID
LEFT JOIN payment p on c.GlobalCollectionID = p.GlobalCollectionID
    AND d.TransactionID = p.TransactionID
LEFT JOIN invoice i on c.GlobalCollectionID = i.GlobalCollectionID
    AND d.TransactionID = i.TransactionID
LEFT JOIN invoicedata id on i.InvoiceID = id.InvoiceID
WHERE c.ProcessDate = '2013-11-29'
    AND c.Item = 11805123
    AND c.CollectionID in ('1104', '1105', '1106')
ORDER BY c.CollectionID
    , d.TransactionID
    , i.InvoiceID
    , p.Account
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you have provided some data and have changed your requirement as well anyway with this new data and new requirement ,    try this

```
DECLARE @T Table (Column1 INT,Column2 INT,Column3 INT,InvoiceNumber INT, InvoiceID INT)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
(1,1,1,1234,1),
(1,1,1,5678,2),
(2,1,1,1287,3),
(2,1,2,1287,3),
(2,2,1,1287,3),
(3,1,1,5555,4),
(3,1,2,5555,4)

;WITH CTE
 AS
   (
   SELECT Column1 ,Column2 
          ,Column3 ,InvoiceNumber , InvoiceID 
          , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ,Column2 ,Column3  ORDER BY InvoiceID ASC)
   FROM @T
   )
 SELECT * FROM CTE
 WHERE rn = 1
```

**Result Set**

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 InvoiceNumber   InvoiceID   rn
   1       1       1    1234               1        1
   2       1       1    1287               3        1
   2       1       2    1287               3        1
   2       2       1    1287               3        1
   3       1       1    5555               4        1
   3       1       2    5555               4        1
```

**Your Query**

```
;WITH CTE
 AS
   (
    SELECT YourQuery.* 
    , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.CollectionID , p.Account , d.TransactionID ORDER BY InvoiceID ASC)
    ( 
     SELECT c.CollectionID
        , p.Account
        , d.TransactionID
        , id.InvoiceNumber
        , i.InvoiceID
    FROM collection c
    INNER JOIN documents d on c.GlobalCollectionID = d.GlobalCollectionID
    LEFT JOIN payment p on c.GlobalCollectionID = p.GlobalCollectionID
        AND d.TransactionID = p.TransactionID
    LEFT JOIN invoice i on c.GlobalCollectionID = i.GlobalCollectionID
        AND d.TransactionID = i.TransactionID
    LEFT JOIN invoicedata id on i.InvoiceID = id.InvoiceID
    WHERE c.ProcessDate = '2013-11-29'
        AND c.Item = 11805123
        AND c.CollectionID in ('1104', '1105', '1106')
      )YourQuery
   )
 SELECT C.CollectionID , C.Account , C.TransactionID,C.InvoiceNumber, C.InvoiceID 
 FROM CTE C
 WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier to help if you'd posted the SQL to your initial query.

You probably want to move your MIN() function into a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT Column1 ,Column2 ,Column3 ,InvoiceNumber , InvoiceID
FROM Table_Name
WHERE InvoiceID = (SELECT MIN(InvoiceID) FROM Table_Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceID
FROM ( 
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1, Column2, Column3
                                ORDER BY InvoiceID ASC)
    FROM example
) e
WHERE rn = 1
```

**See it working on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af3c3/1/0)**. Just swap in your query for the nested query, but keep the `ROW_NUMBER` field.

Produces the correct result set:

```
COLUMN1  COLUMN2  COLUMN3  INVOICENUMBER   INVOICEID
----------------------------------------------------
1        1        1        1234            1
2        1        1        1287            3
2        1        2        1287            3
2        2        1        1287            3
3        1        1        5555            4
3        1        2        5555            4
```